# Прижать красный блок

Tags: html, css, grid

```css
 .m_bl {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max(100px, 30%);
    align-items: start;
    grid-template-areas: 'pl rk' 'cn rk';
 }
 .pl {
    height: 200px;
    background: gold;
    grid-area: pl;
 }
 .content {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    grid-area: cn;
 }
 .rk {
 
    height: 800px;
    background: green;
     grid-area: rk;
 }
```

```html
<div class='m_bl'>
    <div class='pl'></div>
    <div class='content'></div>
    <div class='rk'></div>
</div>
```

Как выполнить так, чтобы красный блок был прижат к желтому, чтобы не расcпологался по центру?

Comment: Привет Дмитрий. Уже устал от SVG? :)  Жду новых вопросов от тебя и хорошо бы вопросы по анимации. Попробуй, что ни-будь сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;

```css
.m_bl {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max(100px, 30%);
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
    align-items: start;
    grid-template-areas: 'pl rk' 'cn rk';
 }
 .pl {
    height: 200px;
    background: gold;
    grid-area: pl;
 }
 .content {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    grid-area: cn;
 }
 .rk {
 
    height: 800px;
    background: green;
     grid-area: rk;
 }
```

```html
<div class='m_bl'>
    <div class='pl'></div>
    <div class='content'></div>
    <div class='rk'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: grid-template-rows: min-content;

Comment: Ок, занимает высоту в зависимости от высоты содержимого. Как в таком случаи ограничить максимальную высоту?

Comment: Но при этом, чтобы изначально отталкиваться от минимальной высоты.

Comment: minmax(0px, auto) 1fr - занимает минимальную высоту

Comment: minmax(0px, 80%)  - Работает, занимает не более 80%. Трудность в том, что занимает он ее как бы сразу все 80%, вместо чтобы отталкиваться от минимальной

Comment: Я не понял чего вы пытаетесь достичь :) Может имеет смысл добавить обертку вокруг контента и поработать с высотой блока внутри обертки?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.m_bl {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr max(100px, 30%);
   grid-template-rows: 200px auto;
}
.pl {
   height: 200px;
   background: gold;
}
.content {
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
.rk {
   height: 800px;
   background: green;
}
```

```html
    <div class='m_bl'>
        <div class='pl'></div>
        <div class='content'></div>
        <div class='rk'></div>
    </div>
```